# What does MATLAB imresize() do if the input image matrix is actually of complex type?

Tags: c++, matlab, complex-numbers

After reading the [`imresize.m` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html), I don't understand what happens if the input image is actually a matrix of complex numbers. I am looking at some code that produces the necessary outputs and it uses `imresize(A,n)` where `A` is the complex matrix and `n` is the resize factor. I have successfully implemented a grayscale version (real double type) of `imresize` with bicubic interpolation in C++ but I have no idea how the function handles complex values.

Edit: More information

I have attempted to perform my currently working bicubic interpolation function to both the real and imaginary parts separately and then adding them together. It does not produce the same results.

Comment: Let's take a step back.  Why is your input type complex-valued?  Resizing images assumes that the data is real or integer.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why the input is complex-valued. I thought it was strange as well and was confident that the algorithm to be ported would not work. But alas, using that imresize() function within the algorithm produces the expected output and the imresize() function within the algorithm also returns another complex matrix that has been resized appropriately.

Comment: Do you use an inverse FFT to get these results? That may explain why they can be complex-valued.

Comment: Do you mean use an ifft after the `imresize` function? If so, no.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that `imresize` works as if applied to real and imaginary part separately. Here is an example to demonstrate the effect:

```
N = 10;
scale = 2;
x = randn(N);
y = randn(N);
z1 = imresize(x+1i*y,scale);
z2 = imresize(x,scale)+1i*imresize(y,scale);
norm(z1-z2) % it is zero
```

In essence, it's just upsampling+filtering, so it would apply to real data in exactly the same w  yas complex data.

Comment: This is not the case. The output of imresize() is a complex-valued matrix that has been properly resized. It does not return a real-valued matrix. Mind you, I do not know what the actual output complex values should be at this point. All I know is that imresize() outputs another complex-valued matrix with the proper resized dimensions. I have implemented the bicubic interpolation function to attempt to handle real and complex values separately...it does not produce the same result.

Comment: And that is exactly what my code demonstrates ;-) Point is this, if the input image is X = Y+iZ, the output image is imresize(Y) + i imresize(Z), i.e., the real part of the input image gets resized to the real part of the output and the imaginary part of the input image gets resized to the imaginary part of the output. As if you had treated them separately.